# Paint cells using as reference text within a clicked cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula, reference

I have data like this in different cells in column F: **3**RG-1S,**22**,**45**YM+1W,**32**VC,**23**
How can I do to once I click on a cell in column F, in this case, rows 3, 22, 45, 32 and 23 get painted in yellow?

Please help, I've been trying to do this, but I don't know how to use those formulas within VBA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celda As Range
Dim rowvalue As Integer
Dim column As Integer
Dim comas As Integer
Dim positioncoma As Integer
Dim newpositioncoma As Integer
Dim contenidocelda As String
Dim i As Long
Dim NumberOfHits As Long
Dim e As Integer

If ActiveCell.value <> "" Then
Range("A1:F500").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

Set celda = ActiveCell

column = ActiveCell.column

    If column = 6 Then 'Only works when clicking cells in column F

            For i = 1 To Len(celda)
            If Mid(celda, i, 1) = "," Then
            NumberOfHits = NumberOfHits + 1
            End If
            Next
            comas = NumberOfHits 'Gets the number of commas in the selected cell
            
    positioncoma = 0 'counter in zero
    
        If comas <> 0 Then 'Loop to find the first numbers for each value within commas and paint those rows in yellow
           For e = 1 To comas
                       
            newpositioncoma = "=IFERROR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "," & celda & "," & positioncoma & "+1),LEN(" & celda & "))"
            contenidocelda = "=MID(" & celda & "," & positioncoma & "+1," & newpositioncoma & "-" & positioncoma & "-1)"
            rowvalue = "=LEFT(" & contenidocelda & ", MATCH(FALSE, ISNUMBER(MID(" & contenidocelda & ", ROW(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "1:" & Chr(34) & "&LEN(" & contenidocelda & ")+1)), 1) *1), 0) -1)"
            Range("A" & rowvalue & ":F" & rowvalue).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            positioncoma = newpositioncoma

           Next e
        Else
            rowvalue = "=LEFT(celda,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(MID(celda,ROW(INDIRECT(" & Chr(34) & "1:" & Chr(34) & "&LEN(celda)+1)),1)*1),0)-1)"
        End If


    Else
        Range("A1:F500").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'unpaint cells once click somewhere else
    End If
Else
 Range("A1:F500").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'unpaint cells if ActiveCell is empty
End If
    
End Sub
```

At the moment I'm using the following code that highlights cells but only when I have a simple number as a value. I can't find a way to get the numbers 3, 22, 45, 32 and 23 from a string like this: **3**RG-1S,**22**,**45**YM+1W,**32**VC,**23**.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rowvalue As Integer

Range("A4:xz90").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

If ActiveCell.column = 6 Then
rowvalue = ActiveCell.Row
Range("A" & rowvalue & ":xz" & rowvalue).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
            
        If VarType(ActiveCell.Value) = 5 Then
         rowvalue = ActiveCell.Value
         Range("A" & rowvalue & ":xz" & rowvalue).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    
End If

End Sub
```

[Example of my worksheet and result when I click cell F69](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nIzs.png)

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but I suppose that you are trying to solve a homework question. It is ok to ask about such, but fair to indicate that in your question. Ok, so why are you using (or attempting to use) worksheet functions in VBA code? VBA has its own functions for string manipulation. Please clarify.

Comment: Why does the 1 in 1S and 1W get missed?  To get count of commas might be easier to get the length of the string, then remove all the commas and get the length of that string and remove one value from the other - `Len(ActiveCell) - Len(Replace(ActiveCell, ",", ""))`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am trying to program a small visual aid for programming a schedule, in my schedule I have activities in column B and their predecessors in column F,  If the predecessor has a number for example 7, means that the activity in Row 7 has to happen before. Whit this visual Aid I will be able to click on any cell in column F and the predecessor activity will be highlighted. The problem starts when I don't have a simple number, and I have something like 11FS-1d,22SS+1d,33,44SS which means that activities 11, 22, 33 and 44 need to happen before, but with certain differences.

Comment: @TomBrunberg as I said in the original question I don't know how to use those formulas within VBA and I know that I can't use worksheet functions in VBA, I just put them there to show how I would solve it. I've looked for days on how to solve it but I couldn't find anything, that's why I posted my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim iRow As Long

Range("A1:F500").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

For Each v In Split(Range("f1"), ",")
    iRow = Val(v)
    If iRow > 0 Then
        Range(Cells(iRow, "A"), Cells(iRow, "F")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
```